# php get the value from hidden field after redirect

Tags: php

- member.php

  ```
  <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
          $membername = $_POST['membername'];

          if(empty($membername))
          {
              $errors .= "Please enter member name<br />";
          }

          if($errors)
          {
              $action = $_POST['submit'];
              echo $errors;
              displayForm();
          }
          else
          {
  ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="mname" value="<?php echo $_POST['membername']; ?>" />
  <?php
              $action = $_POST['submit'];
              header("Location: commit.php?action=$action");
              exit();
          }
      }
      else
      {
          displayForm();
      }
  ?>

  <?php
  function displayForm()
  {
  ?>
      <form action = "member.php" action="post">
          Member Name <input type="text" name="membername" value="<?php if(isset($row['name'])) echo $row['name']; 
          else echo ''; ?>" /><br /><input type="text" name="membername" value=
          <input type="submit" name="submit" name="add" />
      </form>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  ```
- Commit.php

  ```
  <?php
      echo $_POST['mname']; //HERE
  ?>
  ```
- I want to pass the hidden value from member.php. When I run commmit.php, I want to get hidden field value. However, the error is the following:
  **Undefined index: mname in member.php in commit.php.
- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: input field <input type="hidden" name="mname" value="<?php echo $_POST['membername']; ?>" /> is not within the forms open/close tag.

Comment: you should insert hidden field to the form

Comment: The membername input element is missing value and closing. it has error.

Comment: It may seem a bit cryptic but what ^kayra is saying is true. In your displayForm function the input field tag is malformed. You are missing the closing `/>` and value should look like `value=''`

Comment: You will either need to add it to your url - `header("Location: commit.php?action=$action&mname={$_POST['membername']}");` and use `$_GET`, or save it as a `$_SESSION` var as a `header()` will not send the input value as a `$_POST`